# slow sql query - selecting data depending on date interval

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a query that is causing me some trouble. I'm wondering if there is a better way to write this SQL;

```
 SELECT * FROM report 
 WHERE blogid = 1769577 
      AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= datetime
```

so as its faster to fetch the results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you are selecting information for a specific blog, whose data are older than 30 days. and your datetime column does store the data as SQL datetime values. right?

Comment: Rather, the data is less than (or equal to) 30 days old*

Comment: No this is a separate table that stores report data. Contains id, blogid, report_type (int) and datetime. Basically each time a blog is viewed a record gets inserted into this table.

Comment: I think you should post the table create statement here..

Comment: If you have an index on blogid that alone should get you immediate response. Assuming you don't have thousands of posts for one blogid value.

Comment: don't use the * selector. it's bad practice since it creates all kinds of maintenance and code readability problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the query, but you could make sure to have indexes on the blogid and datetime columns

If your table is huge, you might consider horizontal partitioning, which can have a significant impact on performance.  See http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html

Comment: The query works fine except its slow. taking 4 secs or more to get results, table has only 170,000 records ? Datetime is indexed as is blogid.

Comment: @gus, if you have separate indexes on blogid and datetime, mysql can use only one of the indexes. For this query you can have a composite index (blogid,datetime). That might improve the performance a bit.

Comment: Best results were achieved by using a composite index, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL, you can do date arithmetic through +/- operators. I don't know if it would work in MySQL, but you might as well try doing datetime >= (CURDATE() - 30).

```
SELECT * FROM report WHERE blogid = 1769577 AND datetime >= (curdate() - 30)
```

Edit: This blog entry seems to confirm my suggestion: http://mysql-tips.blogspot.com/2005/04/mysql-date-calculations.html

Comment: I think I can use  AND datetime >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the internal datediff() function instead of subtract the interval. like this:

```
datediff(curdate(), datetime) < 30
```

so the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM report WHERE blogid = 1769577 AND datediff(curdate(), datetime) < 30
```

Comment: One thing to note is that if a function is applied on the field in a WHERE clause any index on that field will be unusable. So datetime > (currtime - 30) may be better than (currtime - datetime) < 30.

Answer (score 0):

Guess 1: your `blogid` is not an `int` column. Then you can read the MySQL manual:

> Comparison of dissimilar columns may
>   prevent use of indexes if values
>   cannot be compared directly without
>   conversion. Suppose that a numeric
>   column is compared to a string column.
>   For a given value such as 1 in the
>   numeric column, it might compare equal
>   to any number of values in the string
>   column such as '1', ' 1', '00001', or
>   '01.e1'. This rules out use of any
>   indexes for the string column.

Guess 2: your `blogid` is not indexed.

Guess 3: the reports table is myisam. In this case when you modify data MySQL uses table level locking on the whole `reports` table. You say that every time a blog is viewed a new record is added. These frequent updates may cause table level locking and slow down your select queries.

Otherwise your query is fine.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks i checked it and its int(11)!

Comment: Then post the table create statement so we can examine the indexing. I cannot believe that this query hangs for so long with no apparent reason - (4sec/170K rows).

Comment: Just checked again, that didn't fix it , query cache was on.

Comment: Try to run the query 'outside' of your software, e.g. in sql console. Also check guess 3 in my edited post

Comment: Yes i have mysql front console :)

Comment: Excellent chance to run `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM reports WHERE ...` ;)